# Groovy reflection with a closure

Tags: groovy, jenkins

What is going on here?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method

class MyClass{

   String method1(Closure c){
    println 'method'
    c() + ' method 1'
  }
   String method2(){
    println 'method'
    'method 2'
  }
}


def m = new MyClass()
def c = {'closure'}

println m.method1(c)

Method mr2 = MyClass.getMethod('method2')
println mr2

println mr2.invoke(m)
println '---'

Method mr1 = MyClass.getMethod('method1', c)
println mr1

println mr1.invoke(m)
println '---'
```

which produces this (in the Jenkins groovy console)

```
closure method 1
public java.lang.String MyClass.method2()
method 2
---
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static MyClass.getMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [method1, Script1$_run_closure1@1242bced]
Possible solutions: method2()
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1367)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1353)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:27)
.
.
.
```

Ultimately I want to be able to pass a groovy closure into a java method after picking the method with reflection but I can't seem to get the method with a closure as a parmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
Method mr1 = MyClass.getMethod('method1', c)
println mr1

println mr1.invoke(m)
```

To:

```
Method mr1 = MyClass.getMethod('method1', Closure)
println mr1

println mr1.invoke(m, c)
```

Comment: Thanks, and determine if its a Closure with this `println Closure.isAssignableFrom(c.class)`